# Javascript - Vuejs - Automatic full page smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a page that will be display on a TV (a leaderboard). I am looking for a way to get this page to auto scroll to the bottom, (at a pretty slow rate). Once at the bottom either reset to the top, or ideally maybe just infinity loop from the top.

I have tried a couple methods, but moving them to vue didn't work right. Anyone have any ideas on how to best achieve this?

Comment: What methods did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, I ended up using setInterval() and ScrollBy() and used ScrollTo() when at the bottom to reset to the top.

```
pageScroll() {
  window.setInterval(() => {
    // If at page bottom, scroll by to top
    if((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    else
      // Scroll 1px down
      window.scrollBy(0, 1)
   }, 25)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you  can always  use the html scroll smooth behavior on css

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) & [scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to implement it

Comment: Thanks! I actually use SetInterval() and ScrollBy()

`pageScroll() {
     window.setInterval(() => {
         // If at bottom of page, scroll to top
         if(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)
             window.scrollTo(0, 0)
         else
             window.scrollBy(0, 1)
         }, 25)
 }`